# Changing tabs in a tab control in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am attempting to change to a tab dependent on a treeView node selection:

e.g.

```
private void hostView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedNodeText = e.Node.Text;
    // MessageBox.Show(selectedNodeText);
    tabControl1.SelectTab(selectedNodeText);
}
```

Although when the method runs it returns the following:

> tabControl1.SelectTab(selectedNodeText); >> Value cannot be null.

selectedNodeText is definitely a value / not null, as I tested it using MessageBox.Show

Comment: Seems that your `slectedNodeText` is Null. Check it and you done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the text of your selected node is not null, you'll have to set the `Name` properties of your `TabPages` if you use the `SelectTab` method that takes a string as input.

Set `Name` properties of your TabPages with same values as `Text` properties of your nodes.

*EDIT*:
MSDN is a great resource for developers. In your particular case, when receiving an `ArgumentNullException`, you should have tried to read the [documentation of the `SelectTab` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbt9db4b.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
tabControl1.SelectTab(e.Node.FirstNode.Text);
```